# What is the correct way of posting form data with multiples files and the input field

Tags: jquery, ajaxform, jquery.form.js

I have an implementation for `ajaxSubmit` to post a form input data and multiple files to a backend as:

```
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('pictureId', form.find("[name=pictureId]").val());
    formData.append('description', $('input[name=description]').val());
    formData.append('action', $('input[name=action]').val());


    for (var i = 0; i < filesToUpload.length; i++) {
        formData.append('file[]', filesToUpload[i]);
    }

    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
    }


    $("#frmPicture").ajaxSubmit({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData, 
        success: function (responseText, statusText, xhr, el) {
            debugger;
            if (responseText == "") {
                $("#divAddPictureDialog").dialog("close");
                reloadPictures();
            }
            else {
                $("#spnPictureStatus").html(responseText);
            }
        }
    });
```

But this code gives me an error as:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at init.$.fn.ajaxSubmit (jquery.form.js:97)
    at HTMLDivElement.savePicture (HotelDetails.aspx?id=61364:1576)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.click (jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js:6)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
```

After this I changed my code to `data: {formData}`, the form post happens. But i couldn't access the files on the server. The key `file[]` is never posted to the backend.

Can anyone suggest to me how to properly send the formdata using `jquery.form.js`.

Comment: are you working with php? You don't have a url in your ajax

Comment: no, it's an asp.net application. The form gets submitted automatically to the backend.

Comment: Remove the `{}` and pass the formData object directly to data.... `data:formData`

Comment: yeah, I have done that already, I am getting the error whIch I have mentioned in the question.